# PWA nuxt offlineAssets

Tags: progressive-web-apps, nuxt.js

I try to get precache working with nuxt and the pwa-module and thought offlineAssets is the right place for that. But nothing is prechached, so I guess I'm doing something wrong.

*nuxt.config.js*

```
...
workbox: {
  offlineAssets: [
    '/static/somefile' 
  , '/assets/all_subfolders/*'
  ]
},
...
```

But nothing from this folders is precached. The generated sw.js files has this:

*sw.js*

```
...
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(['/static/somefile', 
'/assets/all_subfolders/*'])
...
```

But the precache stays empty. 
What am I missing?

best regards

Comment: Any progress since?